# Angular 8: How to synchronize Angular Resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning, my question is a bit complicated;

we are inside to ***app.module.ts*** in particular in the ***RouterModule*** area:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'xxx/:xxx', component: XxxComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'homepage', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'homepage', component: HomepageComponent, resolve: {
      answerCallHttp1: CallHttp1Resolve,
      answerCallHttp2: CallHttp2Resolve,
      answerCallHttp3: CallHttp3Resolve
    }},
  {path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent}
])
```

Now my problem is this:

Given that `answerCallHttp1`, `answerCallHttp2`, and `answerCallHttp3` have different response times (for example `answerCallHttp1` has much faster response time than `answerCallHttp2`) **how do I make all `answerCallHttp*` run and then after doing all of them can I load the Homepage component?**

How do I tell the code: "first finish all resolve after load "HomepageComponent"?

I tried to use this method recommended by a user but it generates an infinite loop of Http calls:

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return forkJoin({
      auth: this.memory.isToken(),
      userInfo: this.foo.get(this.api + '/getUserInformation', {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()})}).subscribe(),
      retailers: this.foo.get(this.api + '/retailer', {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()}),params: new HttpParams().set('system_device', 'desktop').set('system_platform', this.getBrowserName())}).subscribe()
    });
  }
```

this is the **all Resolve**:

**callHttp1Resolve.ts**

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {return this.memory.isToken();}
```

**callHttp2Resolve.ts**

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {this.foo.get(this.api + '/getUserInformation', {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()})}).subscribe(userInfo => {return userInfo;});}
```

**callHttp3Resolve.ts**

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {this.foo.get(this.api + '/retailer', {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()}), params: new HttpParams().set('system_device', 'desktop').set('system_platform', this.getBrowserName())}).subscribe(retailer => {return retailer;});}
```

Comment: Could you please say where you intend to call the link?

Answer (score 1):

You may have just one resolver and make all HTTP calls from it:

```js
export class CombinedResolverService implements Resolve<{[key: string]: any}> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    : Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return forkJoin({
        answerCallHttp1: this.http.get(...), // URL 1
        answerCallHttp2: this.http.get(...), // URL 2
        answerCallHttp3: this.http.get(...), // URL 3
      });
  }
}
```

The above approach works only with rxjs versions >= 6.5. If you're using a previous version, you must do:

```js
export class CombinedResolverService implements Resolve<{[key: string]: any}> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    : Observable<{[key: string]: any}> {
    return forkJoin(
        this.http.get(...), // URL 1
        this.http.get(...), // URL 2
        this.http.get(...), // URL 3
      ).pipe(
        map(([answerCallHttp1, answerCallHttp2, answerCallHttp3]) => ({
            answerCallHttp1, answerCallHttp2, answerCallHttp3
          }))
      );
  }
}
```

## I'd suggest the following changes:

### call1HttpResolve.ts

As `isToken()` is *not* an observable, we'll turn it into an observable with the `of` operator (`forkJoin`, above, demands its return to be an observable):

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
  : Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
  return of(this.memory.isToken());
}
```

### call2HttpResolve.ts

You must **return** the observable here:

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
  : Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
  return this.foo.get(this.api + '/getUserInformation', 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()})});
}
```

### call3HttpResolve.ts

You must **return** the observable here:

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
  : Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
  return this.foo.get(this.api + '/retailer', {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Auth': this.memory.getToken()}), 
    params: new HttpParams()
        .set('system_device', 'desktop')
        .set('system_platform', this.getBrowserName())
    });
}
```

### Finally, in your component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data
    .subscribe(({answerCallHttp1, answerCallHttp2, answerCallHttp3}) => {
      // do whatever you want with the data
    });
}
```

**[Final comment]:** BTW, @mbojko has a good observation in another answer. I checked what he is suggesting and it works (and I learned a new feature, that's great!), so you'd have to do only the suggested changes in `call2HttpResolve.ts` and `call3HttpResolve.ts`. It's the least effort path and equally efficient.

You can see it working in this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma615237216433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You get that out of the box: the view is built only after all the resolvers are done.

You can verify it by putting a few console.log statements in your component's `ngOnInit` and in the resolvers themselves (like: `return this.httpClient.get(/* ... */).pipe(tap(() => console.log('Request completed'))`).